# android - cannot resolve symbol FileProvider

Tags: android

I am trying to test the FileProvider [tutorial](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider.html).

It asks to include in the manifest :

```
<provider
    android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
    android:authorities="com.mydomain.fileprovider"
    android:exported="false"
    android:grantUriPermissions="true">
</provider>
```

In the manifest, I get the error:

```
 Cannot resolve symbol FileProvider
```

I followed these [instructions](https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html), to add the v4 support library to Android Studio. I add the following to the build.gradle file, but the gradle sync fails :

```
 compile "com.android.support:support-v4:18.0.+"
```

What must I do to resolve this problem ?

Comment: How does/did the gradle sync fail? What error

Answer (score 2):

Go to File > Invalidate Caches / Restart and Invalidate and Restart.

Comment: Not Working, even wasted my time by restarting all studio and projects.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the version of the support library you are targeting (18.0.+) is too low.
FileProvider was [only added in version 22.1.0](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider.html) according to the reference docs so you will need at least:

```
compile "com.android.support:support-v4:22.1.0"
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this too late in case you got same problem please refer

https://stackoverflow.com/a/58784995/5193899

```
<provider
        android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="com.camera.app.fileprovider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/file_paths">

        </meta-data>
    </provider>
```