# Why do FileProvider.getUriForFile cause runtime exception

Tags: java, android, android-camera, android-fileprovider

I follow the [Android Developers tutor](https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html) for taking and saving a picture. 
The call to `FileProvider.getUriForFile` in the following code fragment produce `runtime error`.

Exception -

```
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to find 
configured root that contains /storage/sdcard/Android
/data/com.example.myfirstapp/files/Pictures/JPEG_20161121_150916_-
1008254408.jpg
```

**Java** -

```
if (photoFile != null) {
                Uri photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this,
                        "com.example.myfirstapp.fileprovider",
                        photoFile);
                takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI);
                startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO);
            }
```

**Manifest.xml** -

```
<provider
        android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="com.example.myfirstapp.fileprovider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/file_paths"></meta-data>
    </provider>
```

Comment: Please edit your question and provide the contents of your `file_paths.xml` file. Also, please show how you are creating the value for `photoFile`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like the problem was in defining the provider within the Manifest file.

Found a solution here [ANSWER](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38516646/fileprovider-error)

Thanks to [ImagineThat](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5927903/imaginethat)